# Django create composite attribute

Tags: django, django-models

If I have a Person modle as below:

```
class Person
    first_name = models.CharField
    last_name = models.CharField
```

I want to create a composite attribute full name, which would be a combination of first and last name.

```
full_name = self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

Also, whenever a the first name in the person model is modified the full_name should be automatically update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that this could be done by overriding the custom save method.

```
class Person
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()
    full_name = models.CharField()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.full_name = self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
    super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just make it a [property](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) on the model.

```
class Person(...):
   ...
  @property
  def full_name(self):
    return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Comment: How could I update this property(full_name) when a change is made to the first name or last name? Also, is there a way to set unique constrain on this property?

Comment: It would never need updating and it would never need a constraint since it doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: Is there a way to create a composite attribute which could be saved to the database?

Comment: Sure, [but that would be silly.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: This model was just an example. In my project I am creating a natural key based on three other fields in the modle. If I am not storing my composite attribute to the database I wont be able to perform queries on the composite attribute. That is one of the reason I want this composite attribute to be saved to the database.

Comment: Joel I think you should ask the _actual_ question which I believe is - _"How do I define a composite key in django models?"_ and the answer to that is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270808/compound-composite-primary-unique-key-with-django) (also answered by Ignacio).